# ReplayKit - Broadcast Upload Extension - EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY

Tags: xcode11, replaykit, ios13.3, rpbroadcastsamplehandler

It seems that I encounter a bug from Apple ReplayKit extension.

How to reproduce:
under Xcode 11.3.1 with a device iPhone 6S under iOS 13.3.1

if you try to debug an empty Broadcast Upload Extension under ANY application. 
if you authorize the microphone access AFTER the broadcast started. 
You will get `EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY` error

Comment: I have a similar issue. Please file a bug via feedbackassistant.apple.com. More feedbacks mean they'll fix it sooner.

Comment: I did file a bug via feedbackassistant under the name: ReplayKit - Broadcast Upload Extension - EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY crash

Comment: Did you get any solution for the same?